# Issues with City Selection and Error Handling in Country-State-City Dropdowns

Tags: flutter

I've been utilizing the [country_state_city](https://pub.dev/packages/country_state_city) package to interact with APIs for retrieving information about countries, states, and cities. Below, I've outlined how my methods are structured:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _getCountries();
  });
}

List<String> _countries = [], _cities = [], _states = [], _countryCodes = [], _isoCodes = [];
String? _selectedCountryCode, _selectedStateCode;

Future<List<String>> _getCountries() async {
  final countries = await getAllCountries();
  setState(() {
    for (Country country in countries) {
      _countries.add(country.name);
      _countryCodes.add(country.isoCode);
    }
  });
  return _countries;
}

Future<List<String>> _getStates(String countryCode) async {
  final states = await getAllStates();
  setState(() {
    _states.clear();
    for (States.State state in states) {
      if (state.countryCode == countryCode) {
        _states.add(state.name);
        _isoCodes.add(state.isoCode);
      }
    }
  });

  return _states;
}

Future<List<String>> _getCities(String isoCode, String countryCode) async {
  final cities = await getAllCities();
  setState(() {
    _cities.clear();
    for (City city in cities) {
      if (city.stateCode == isoCode && city.countryCode == countryCode)
        _cities.add(city.name);
    }
  });
  return _cities;
}
```

These methods are invoked within my custom dropdown widget:

```
CustomDropdownCl(
  items: _countries.toList(),
  hint: 'Country',
  isRequired: true,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      country.text = newValue!;
      _selectedCountryCode =
          _countryCodes[_countries.indexOf(newValue)];
      _getStates(_selectedCountryCode!);
    });
  },
  textEditingController: country,
  isCountryCity: true,
),
CustomDropdownCl(
  items: _states,
  hint: 'State',
  isRequired: true,
  onChanged: (newValue) async {
    setState(() {
      state.text = newValue!;
      _selectedStateCode =
          _isoCodes[_states.indexOf(newValue)];
    });
    await _getCities(
        _selectedStateCode!, _selectedCountryCode!);
  },
  textEditingController: state,
  isCountryCity: true,
),
CustomDropdownCl(
  items: _cities,
  hint: 'City',
  isRequired: true,
  onChanged: (newValue) async {
    setState(() {
      city.text = newValue!;
    });
  },
  textEditingController: city,
  isCountryCity: true,
),
```

However, I'm encountering two issues:

1. I'm unable to select a city as an unreadable error message shows up after selecting state.
2. Whenever I change the country after selecting a state, I encounter an unreadable error message.

This is what it looks like
[image]